# Eclipse aarch64 and OpenJDK (ARM)

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, apple-silicon

I'm trying out the Eclipse 4.20 builds available as [Mac OSX (64 bit version for Arm64/AArch64)](https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.20-202106111600/) running under macOS 11 on Apple Silicon. This version doesn't seem to come with a jdk, so I've assumed I need to handle that myself. I installed 16.0.1-librca from Bellsoft with SDKman (Rosetta2 mode false).

I edited the info.plist file of Eclipse like this:

```
<key>Eclipse</key>          
<array>
  <string>-vm</string>
  <string>~/.sdkman/candidates/java/16.0.1-librca/bin/java</string>
…(Other stuff here)
</array>
```

and Eclipse does indeed startup, but crashes right away. A while after this macOS claims I don't have the permissions to start the app. Results are identical with the Zulu AArch64.

I typically get

> "Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
> KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000000000000c"

and

> "Application Specific Information: abort() called"

in libjvm.dylib.

This with some variations depending on the setup used.

Assuming these releases are supposed to work in macOS 11 on Apple Silicon, then it would seem likely this should be possible to get working. Or have I misunderstood the meaning of aarch64 here? Are these perhaps just versions for jdk developers? I looked over the "Target Environments" for Eclipse and feel unsure what other uses a version labelled as "Mac…for Arm64/AArch64" would have here.

libexec doesn't see the SDKman installed version. When I run `java --version` in the terminal it does show "openjdk 16.0.1 2021-04-20" and not my main Oracle JDK.

Any suggestions on how to set this up?

Comment: Just to be clear without the edits Eclipse complains about the main Oracle JDK and won't start at all.

Comment: I believe the Azul Java 11 macOS arm64 JDK was used for testing - https://www.azul.com/downloads/?package=jdk#download-openjdk but Java 16 should work as well. It is more usual to edit the eclipse.ini to specify the -vm argument.

Comment: It has to be an AArch64 Java too. The OpenJDK you have is probably a non AArch64 HotSpot VM. So either use the Azul macOS ARM 64 bit (as greg-449 said) or the OpenJDK OpenJ9 macOS aarch64 VM: https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk16&jvmVariant=openj9

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Actually, @howlger, with rosetta 2 set to "false" in SDKMan means I should only have gotten native releases listed and "16.0.1-librca" was among these. But I'll try the others as well.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449, I tried editing Eclipse.ini but that made no difference at all. I also tried pointing to "libjli.dylib" as well and that didn't work at all either.

Comment: So now I tried also with Zulu and results are identical.

Comment: If it starts and then crashes, what does the crash say? Does it produce a log file?

Comment: @greg-449, I typically get "Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000000000000c" 
and
"Application Specific Information:
abort() called"
 in libjvm.dylib. 

This with some variations depending on the setup used.

Comment: You probably need to report this on [Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/) with as much information as possible

Comment: @howlger, it seems there is no aarch64 build for macOS 11 at AdoptOpenJDK. Even the nightly builds all seem to be x64 only.

Comment: Your right, I was wrong. There are no AdoptOpenJDK macOS aarch64 builds yet. There will be a [HotSpot macOS aarch64 VM for Java 17 (JEP 391)](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/391), and [for OpenJ9 see issue #11164](https://github.com/eclipse-openj9/openj9/issues/11164).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have yet to investigate the actual reason, but after I had installed the "OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu (build 11.0.11+9-LT)" and I had started to contemplate [overriding eclipse.ini](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_macOS_Example) in order to avoid macOS preventing me from starting a modified app (recurrent issue. Note I didn't attempt overriding) I started Eclipse from the command line with the open command and Eclipse starts right up using

```
-vm 
/Users/[user name]/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.11-zulu/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/`
```

At least this starts Eclipse. Double clicking the app renders the same results as before.

A theory is that since the open command runs in the terminal and java --version verifies the zulu jdk set there by sdkman, this is why. However JAVA_HOME is empty and the /usr/libexec/java_home -V command only lists the Oracle JDK.

Thank you @greg-449 and @howlger. I don't think I'd found this without your helpful suggestions.

To not have to be in the terminal just for starting Eclipse I made this little Applescript that opens Terminal (Just executing the command without it involved wouldn't supply the proper JVM):

```
on run {input, parameters}

tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "open /Applications/Eclipse.app"
    delay 1
    close front window
end tell
```

Save that as an app and start with this instead of Eclipse.

If I could find out how the proper JVM in Terminal is supplied to Eclipse with the open command, maybe this can be used for modifying how Eclipse starts.