# Spring Tools Suite 4 for aarch64 macOS 11 M1, where?

Tags: macos, apple-m1, spring-tools-4

According the blog post "[Spring Tools 4.11.0 released](https://spring.io/blog/2021/06/21/spring-tools-4-11-0-released)" by @Martin Lippert on June 21st there are

> "early-access builds for Apple Silicon platform (ARM M1) available"
> for this 4.11 version.

However, there seem to be no findable places to download those. I've seen there are Eclipse downloads native for Mac ARM (aarch64), but no STS as far as I can see. Anyone know where these early-access builds for Apple Silicon are available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the early-access version of Spring Tools 4 for Apple Silicon from here: http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/STS4/nightly-distributions.html

Due to a bug in the build scripts, the 4.11.0.RELEASE build for Apple Silicon ended up containing the wrong bits, so you should go with the nightly build for Apple Silicon for now.

Comment: Thanks @martin lippert. However, how are you supposed to start the app? I thought the jvm was included inside the application, yet STS tries to load the main non-aarch64 Oracle jvm and ignores my SDKMan aarch64 installations. It's not possible in macOS 11 to edit the .ini file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68060961/eclipse-aarch64-and-openjdk-arm for more on this problem using just Eclipse. The terminal open command seems to be the only workaround that somehow supplies the SDKMan jvm.

Comment: The M1 builds of STS4 do not include a JDK yet, so we rely on the launcher to pick up the JRE from your system or have you modify the .ini file to point to the right JDK. Thanks for the pointer to the mentioned thread on SO, that is definitely helpful here. Nevertheless I wonder if it is possible to edit the .ini file. Usually, if you started the app once, you can go ahead and modify those files and start the app again.