# SpringToolSuite 4 and proper OSGi clean

Tags: osgi, spring-tool-suite

I have SpringToolSuite 4 installed in macOS 11 "Big Sur" running in aarch64 of Zulu11 OpenJDK 11.0.11+9-LTS . I get this error below when starting up and have added the "-clean" parameter to the two ways I use to start up.
From an Applescript: `open /Applications/SpringToolSuite4.app" & " --args -clean`
Or from the command line: `./SpringToolSuite4 -clean`

It would seem the clean parameter is successfully sent as '-Dosgi.clean="true"' is on the last line below. However, it doesn't seem to help as this is reappearing at every restart.

Are there other ways to do an OSGi clean?

I can't edit the ini-file because macOS will clampdown on this and render the whole installation invalid. Since the clean command seems to get passed, that is likely unnecessary.

Error message:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ~/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna13221667715595625418.tmp: dlopen(~/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna13221667715595625418.tmp, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
> ~/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna13221667715595625418.tmp: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
> ~/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna13221667715595625418.tmp: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
> ~/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna13221667715595625418.tmp: dlopen(~/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna13221667715595625418.tmp, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
> ~/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna13221667715595625418.tmp: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
> ~/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna13221667715595625418.tmp: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
> java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
> java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2442)
> java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2498)
> java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2694)
> java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2627)
> java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:768)
> java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1837)
> com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:1018)
> com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:988)
> com.sun.jna.Native.(Native.java:195)
> com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.UnixDomainSocket.(UnixDomainSocket.java:80)
> com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.ApacheDockerHttpClientImpl$2.createSocket(ApacheDockerHttpClientImpl.java:124)
> com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:125)
> com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:409)
> com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.connectEndpoint(InternalExecRuntime.java:164)
> com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.connectEndpoint(InternalExecRuntime.java:174)
> com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ConnectExec.execute(ConnectExec.java:135)
> com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
> com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57)
> com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:165)
> com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
> com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57)
> com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpRequestRetryExec.execute(HttpRequestRetryExec.java:93)
> com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
> com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57)
> com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:116)
> com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
> com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57)
> com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ContentCompressionExec.execute(ContentCompressionExec.java:128)
> com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
> com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:178)
> com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:67)
> com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.ApacheDockerHttpClientImpl.execute(ApacheDockerHttpClientImpl.java:157)
> com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.ZerodepDockerHttpClient.execute(ZerodepDockerHttpClient.java:8)
> com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultInvocationBuilder.execute(DefaultInvocationBuilder.java:228)
> com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultInvocationBuilder.get(DefaultInvocationBuilder.java:202)
> com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultInvocationBuilder.get(DefaultInvocationBuilder.java:75)
> com.github.dockerjava.core.exec.InfoCmdExec.exec(InfoCmdExec.java:24)
> com.github.dockerjava.core.exec.InfoCmdExec.exec(InfoCmdExec.java:14)
> com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd.exec(AbstrDockerCmd.java:35)
> org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.dash.docker.runtarget.DockerRunTarget.connect(DockerRunTarget.java:130)
> org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.dash.cloudfoundry.RemoteBootDashModel.lambda$2(RemoteBootDashModel.java:77)
> org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.dash.model.remote.RefreshStateTracker.call(RefreshStateTracker.java:80)
> org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.dash.model.remote.RefreshStateTracker.lambda$3(RefreshStateTracker.java:123)
> org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.core.util.JobUtil$6.run(JobUtil.java:193)
> org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
> -Dosgi.clean="true"

Comment: There is some background why I can't edit the ini file in this older question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68060961/eclipse-aarch64-and-openjdk-arm

Answer (score 1):

The issue mentioned above is this: https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/684

It is not related to OSGi, so `-clean` doesn't help here. The fix will be part of STS 4.12.1 release, but you could grab a nightly CI build to get the fix right away from here: http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/STS4/nightly-distributions.html

On a related note: Once you started STS at least one you should be able to modify the .ini file without issues. If macOS still complains about it, you can remove the quarantine flag from the app:

`sudo xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine SpringToolSuite4.app`

This will avoid the error message and let you start your STS4 install even after editing the content.

Comment: Thanks @Martin Lippert, I do have tried with "xattr" already months ago and it did not help. Once macOS has decided to prevent Eclipse from starting, after having edited the ini file, only a complete reinstallation reinstates it.

I will, however, revisit this as you suggest it. macOS 11 has been updated quite a bit and maybe this behavior I've encountered wasn't intended when I tried this last.

Comment: And please take a look at the CI builds for the fix for the docker integration on M1.